# Pytorch, sample given batch logits

Tags: pytorch

Given logits like

```py
# each row is a record of data
logits = np.array([ [0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.3, 0.1, 0.5], [0.1, 0.3, 0.0] ])
```

How can I use Pytorch to sample the index for the logits of each row? Current distribution APIs does not support such functions.

What I want is, for example

```py
distribution = Categorical(logits=logits)
labels = distribution.sample(dim=1)
```